# Regex match first instance only

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

For some reason I am not able to use lazy matching.

Here is the text -

```
 806 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  823 ?        S      0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  824 ?        S      0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  825 ?        S      0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  826 ?        S      0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  827 ?        S      0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

and I want to match only first line which has "apache2" i.e.

```
806 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

my regex looks like this -

```
(apache)?
```

but it doesn't seem to be working- its matching all instances. What's wrong?

Comment: because '?'  means "find zero or one of the thing that comes before this question mark."

Comment: You don't need to parse `ps` for this. Look at `/var/run/apache2.pid` or similar on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `(apache)?` means approximately "match either *apache* or *not apache*", so it will obviously match everything.

You didn't specify which programming language or regex flavor you are using, but this regex would match a whole row containing the word *apache*:

```
.*apache.*
```

This would of course match **all** the lines containing the word *apache*, so it's up to you to use the programming language you are using to get only the very first match.

Note: If your regex flavor of choice matches newlines with the dot, then you might need to go in multiline mode and add the start of line and end of line anchors, like this:

```
^.*apache.*$
```

(and then remember to turn the multiline mode on!)